# Laravel 8 factory state afterCreating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

Laravel 7 factories had method **afterCreatingState()** where you could define what should happen after Model with specific state was saved into database.

```
$factory->afterCreatingState(App\User::class, 'active', function ($user, $faker) {
    // ...
});
```

Laravel 8 factories don't have this method, instead there is only general **afterCreating()**.

```
public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterCreating(function (User $user) {
        //
    });
}
```

How to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is possible to define this behavior right in the state definition method.

```
public function active()
{
    return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
        return [
            'active' => true,
        ];
    })->afterCreating(function (User $user) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: I think, this is not an answer of your question. . It should possibly be an edit of your question

Comment: ^^^ Disagree this is definitely an answer. A helpful one at that judging by the upvotes. I actually didn't realize they answered their own question until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

***after crating - state***

```
public function active()
    {
        return $this->state([
            'active' => true,
        ])->afterCreating(function (Article $user) {
            // ...
        });
    }
```

***Configure the model factory.***

```
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (User $user) {
            //
        });
    }
```